# Set focus in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I want my focus in the `CenterPanel.java`, but the focus is in the `TopPanel.java` class.

#### Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

#### MainFrame.java

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        super();
        setTitle("Title");
        setVisible(true);
        MainPanel mainpanel = new MainPanel();
        setContentPane(mainpanel);
        pack();
    }
}
```

#### MainPanel.java (Called from `Main.java`)

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private TopPanel topPanel;
    private CenterPanel centerPanel;
    public MainPanel() {
        createComponents();
        addComponents();
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        centerPanel = new CenterPanel();
        topPanel = new TopPanel(centerPanel);
    }

    private void addComponents() {
        add(centerPanel);
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

#### TopPanel.java

```
public class TopPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton aButton;
    private CenterPanel centerPanel;

    public TopPanel(CenterPanel c) {
        centerPanel = c;
        createComponents();
        addComponents();
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        aButton = new Button("Button");
    }

    private void addComponents() {
        add(aButton);
    }
}
```

#### CenterPanel.java

```
public class CenterPanel extends JPanel {
    public CenterPanel() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
        requestFocus();

        addKeyListener(new MoveController());
    }
}
```

#### MoveController.java

```
public class MoveController extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Released");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `requestFocusInWndow()`, not requestFocus(). Read the API documentation for the reason.

Also, you can only request focus on a component when the component is displayed in a visible GUI. Given the structure of your code it is not easy to access the "CenterPanel" once you make the GUI visible.

Check out [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) which shows how you can use the `RequestFocusListener` to request focus on a component even when the GUI is not yet visible.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `setVisible(true)` to be the last in you `main()` method

Move the `requestFocus();` call from the constructor and call it after the layout is done (may be even after the `setVisible()` call.

NOTE: It's better to use KeyBindings rather than KeyListener to rpocess separate events. KeyListener is good if you need realy multiple key events (e.g. typing)